# Processing pytest test results at runtime

Tags: python, pytest

So I have have pytest run my tests and that's great, but I want to actually do something with the test results.  I was using unittest, and that gives me a swanky results object that I can process after the tests have run.  Pytest just seems to give me a big text dump - writing a parser for that sounds mind-numbingly boring.

How do I get the results into something I can use?  I must be missing something.

btw - I'm running my tests using pytest.main(), not via the command line py.test.  I was hoping to have some sort of result object I can interact with at runtime.  I realize I can write results to disk, read from disk, parse said results and then act on results - but it seems like those disk operations are just extra steps I should be able to avoid.

Comment: You can get formatted text files and xml files directly from pytest with the flags `--junitxml=path` or `--resultlog=path`.

Answer (score 2):

py.test result files are not really meant to be human readable. I'm not sure if there is a third-party parser for them or not. They are meant to be read by a continuous integration server like [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) or [Travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/). As @limelights said you get the xml files for these services with the `--junitxml=path` flag. More [here](http://pytest.org/latest/usage.html#creating-junitxml-format-files). or with the `--resultlog=path` flag. More [here](http://pytest.org/latest/usage.html#creating-resultlog-format-files).

Comment: I really don't want an external file at all.  But I suppose the junitxml option gives me something that is at least usable.  I was hoping for json or some other python object that I could interact with.

Comment: I have a project on [github](https://github.com/cwandrews/tojson) that will read in the file and convert it to json.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do some introspection with the `session` object

you can play around in the `pytest_sessionfinish` callback to inspect the session object and see what crawling actions you can do over it. I know you can get the test case names and paths and all that, but their final result status is proving elusive to me to locate in a quick time.

```py
def pytest_sessionfinish(session):
    type(session)
    session
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()
```

```
(Pdb) type(session)
<class '_pytest.main.Session'>
(Pdb) session
<Session driving_develop_fw exitstatus=<ExitCode.TESTS_FAILED: 1> testsfailed=1 testscollected=2>


(Pdb) for d in dir(session): print(d)
CollectError
Failed
Interrupted
__class__
__delattr__
__dict__
__dir__
__doc__
__eq__
__format__
__ge__
__getattribute__
__gt__
__hash__
__init__
__init_subclass__
__le__
__lt__
__module__
__ne__
__new__
__reduce__
__reduce_ex__
__repr__
__setattr__
__sizeof__
__str__
__subclasshook__
__weakref__
_bestrelpathcache
_collect
_collectfile
_fixturemanager
_initialparts
_initialpaths
_matchnodes
_name2pseudofixturedef
_node_cache
_node_location_to_relpath
_nodeid
_norecursepatterns
_notfound
_parsearg
_perform_collect
_pkg_roots
_prunetraceback
_recurse
_repr_failure_py
_setupstate
_tryconvertpyarg
_visit_filter
add_marker
addfinalizer
collect
config
exitstatus
extra_keyword_matches
fspath
genitems
get_closest_marker
gethookproxy
getparent
ihook
isinitpath
items
iter_markers
iter_markers_with_node
keywords
listchain
listextrakeywords
listnames
matchnodes
name
nodeid
own_markers
parent
perform_collect
pytest_collectreport
pytest_collectstart
pytest_runtest_logreport
repr_failure
session
setup
shouldfail
shouldstop
startdir
teardown
testscollected
testsfailed
trace
warn
```

It is the items that are the individual test cases that were collected during the run. The `session.testscollected` and `session.testsfailed` give you a count for how many tests were collected and how many failures were seen across those tests.

Fyi the session reference seems to show up a few times down the hierarchy.

```
(Pdb) hex(id(session))
'0x7fb717b1dcf8'
(Pdb) hex(id(session.items[1].session))
'0x7fb717b1dcf8'
```